# Embed .gif files in email body after a function call

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to embed **`.gif`** files in the mail body.

But I'm using a **`RangetoHTML`** function to paste a range of my Excel sheet into the email body.

I want to embed the **`.gif`** files below the range, in the mail body, instead of adding the **`MyGif.gif`** as an attachment.

Following is the code snippet:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd")

With Dest
    .SaveAs Destination & "MyFile" & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "abc@email.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"

        .Attachments.Add MyGif
        .HTMLBody = "<br><B>My HTML Body</B><br>" _
                    & RangetoHTML(Source) 
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
 .Close savechanges:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Embed an **`Gif`** file in the mail body try the following,

```
    With olMail
        .To = "0m3r@EMail.com"

        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"

        .Attachments.Add "C:\Temp\MyGif.gif"

        .HTMLBody = "<br><B>My HTML Body</B><br>" _
                    & RangetoHTML(Source) _
                    & .HTMLBody & "<br>Here is Your Embedded GIF File:<br>" _
                    & "<img src='MyGif.gif'><br>" 

'        .Send   'or use .Display
        .Display
    End With
```